# logically valid - invalid based on statements and conclusions.

Tags: logic

Which of the following conclusions is logically valid based on statement given below?

Statement: Most of the Indian states existed before independence.

Conclusions:

(I) Some Indian States existed before independence.

(II) All Indian States did not exist before independence.

source: http://netexam.pmgurus.com/ugc-net-online-questions.aspx?q=ugc-net-exam-question-papers-with-answer-paper-june-2006&gid=91&h=24&QID=5970&Qno=28

I guess the answer is both I and II are true but it turns out to be wrong. What is the logically valid approach to solve such a problem?

Comment: Why you think second is true?

Comment: (II) means: No Indian state existed before independence. Which contradicts your statement.

Comment: What is the answer according to you? its pretty confusing

Comment: The answer is (I)

Comment: but the answer according to the university is only (II)